# How to increase the number of peers of an organization in the existing network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I have 2 peers of an organization now, how to increase the number of peers of an organization in the existing network

Comment: I answered the question below, but it would be more helpful if you added more detail about what you have already tried to do

Answer (score 2):

Adding a peer to an existing organization is straightforward:

1) Obtain the identity for the peer

You need to provide the local MSP information for the peer.
Since you already have two peers, you likely already have a certificate authority (e.g. the Fabric CA) set up to issue certificates.  You simply need to register and enroll an identity for the peer and then use that to populate the MSP folder for the peer.

For the admincerts folder of the MSP, you can copy the material from the MSPs of either of the existing peers.

2) Install chaincode

Determine which chaincode you want to run on this peer and install it using the admin identity for the peer.

3) Join channels

If you want the peer to join existing channels, you'll need to fetch the initial config block for the channel (you can use the CLI to do this - `peer channel fetch ...` ) and then use that to join the peer to the channel